# How do i add two banners in Magento homepage next to my flexslider?

Tags: css, magento, content-management-system, flexslider, banner

I had a camera.js slider in my website which i replaced for a Flexslider. I did this because i could not make the camera.js slider clickable and i wanted to get rid of the 'Click here' button. Now i have the flexslider fitted in my website i want to bring back two banners which where in my site next to my camera.js slider, but i do not get it working...

This is my homepage, as you can see the banners do not show on the right of the slider but they show at the wrong place:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yESl9.jpg

I want to have two banners in size 381 x 219 on the right of the slider, one above another.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="25"}}
</script>
<ul class="banner-block-right">
<li><a href="{{store url='nieuwe-producten'}}"> <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-8.png'}}" alt="" /> </a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='klantenservice'}}"> <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-7.png'}}" alt="" /> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Just to clearify:

- I used the code: script type="text/javascript">// etc

because i had a problem with the navigation bar, it did not work anymore when i put the new slider in.

- I placed the slider in a widget just because i thought that would be easier.

So my question is, what adjust do i have to make in the code to have the two little banners next to the flexslider?

Btw. When i used the script to get my navigation bar working, the default magento pricing layout came back, it was like get the navigation bar working or get the magento pricing in the correct layout. I choose the navigation bar lol, does someone know a fix for this?

EDIT: CSS code of the flexslider

```
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.0
 * http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 */


/* Browser Resets */
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/ 
.flexslider {max-width: 700px; margin: -20; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */

.flexslider .slides img { 
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: - auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your CSS.

Check if:

- Your banner-block-right class doesn't have a 'clear' style rule on it. 'Clear' clears the floats.
- Check if both the slider and the banner-block-right have a float rule.
- Check if the slider isn't too wide.

If it doesn't work maybe you could post the relevant parts of your css.

**Update after seeing the webpage**

The problem is your ul element isn't nested within the div row. Inspecting your webpage gives me the following nesting structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <script         src="http://www.site.nl/js/magestore/bannerslider/jquery.flexslider.js">
            <link media="all" href="http://www.site.nl/skin/frontend/base/default/css/magestore/bannerslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <div class="flexslider flexslider-7-1">
            <script type="text/javascript">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</div>
<ul class="banner-block-right">
```

So your widget is closing the .container and the .row divs. The template you are inserting probably has to much div closing tags at the end.

Comment: I updated the original post with the CSS code of the flexslider, the max width of the slider should be correct, it is 700px. The banner block has a float: right, rule.

Comment: Try to give the .flexslider class a float: left;

Comment: Is the website live at the moment? I need to inspect it to know what is going on.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the right one, since it fixed your first question? Thanks. Your script issue is another question. I would try instead of pulling the slider and banners out of the .container, putting it in the .container. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! That helped me out! It is now how it needs to be! Thank you very much!

I got rid of the widget, and i pasted the code in to cms after the 3 closing divs. Now it is also responsive :)

Only thing that is still a problem is that because of the use of the script to keep the dropdown working is that it changes the layout of the pricing to the default magento... how do i fix this?

Comment: and the thing is that it places the banners on a weird place when width 967 till 1167